# How to replace \n with new line in Atom

Tags: regex, ide, atom-editor

How can I replace all the "\n" occurrences in a text in Atom and turn them into break lines?

I'd like to turn this:

```
Description:\nEC2
```

Into this:

```
Description:
EC2
```

Answer (score 3):

I've realized it was simply by activating the "Use Regex" option in [Find and Replace](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/find-and-replace/) (the ".*" button at the right side) and escaping the first \n expression with another backlash.

So, by searching **\\n** I'll get all the \n occurrences and by replacing them with **\n** I'll turn them into break lines.

[image]